# Why is my filehandler empty?? PERL

Tags: perl, null, file-handling

I am completely new to Perl and I have a section of code that is giving me back a empty filehandler.

```
my $md5dir = "...plib/test/md5sum";    #IN MY PROG, IS THE FULL PATH
opendir( DIR, $md5dir ) or die "Can't open directory $md5dir: $!";
my @md5files = grep !/^\.\.?$/, readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);

if (  scalar @md5files < 1
   || scalar @md5files > 8
   || ( scalar @md5files % 2 != 0 ) )
{
   print "Incorrect amount of files in directory. Aborting.\n";
   exit 1;
}
else {
   for ( my $i = 0; ( $i < scalar @md5files / 2 ); $i++ ) {
      my $file1 = $md5files[$i];
      open( my $fh1, $file1 ) or die "Fail to open file $file1 $!";
      my $file2 = $md5files[ $i + 3 ];
      open( my $fh2, $file2 ) or die "Fail to open file $file2 $!";
      print "2.", $file1, " ", $file2, "\n";
      my $first1 = substr( $file1, 0, 4 );
      my $first2 = substr( $file2, 0, 4 );
      if ( ( $first1 cmp $first2 ) == 0 ) {
         if   ( eof $fh1 ) { print "No lines\n"; }
         else              { my $line1 = <$fh1>; print "$line1\n"; }
         if   ( eof $fh2 ) { print "No lines2\n"; }
         else              { my $line2 = <$fh2>; print "$line2\n"; }
         close $fh1;
         close $fh2;
      }
   }    # for
}    # else
```

The output is such:

```
2.SAM5_27-04-2016_11:21:20.md5 SAM5_27-04-2016_11:20:11.md5
No lines
No lines2
2.SAM6_27-04-2016_11:18:25.md5 SAM6_25-04-2016_10:38:38.md5
No lines
No lines2
2.SAM4_27-04-2016_11:19:06.md5 SAM4_27-04-2016_11:17:22.md5
No lines
No lines2
```

In the directory for md5sum:

```
:md5sum>ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxr-x   2 ateam    ateam       4096 Apr 27 11:24 ./
drwxrwxr-x   4 ateam    ateam       4096 Apr 27 11:24 ../
-rw-rw-r--   1 ateam    ateam         63 Apr 27 11:17 SAM4_27-04-2016_11:17:22.md5
-rw-rw-r--   1 ateam    ateam         63 Apr 27 11:19 SAM4_27-04 2016_11:19:06.md5
-rw-rw-r--   1 ateam    ateam         63 Apr 27 11:20 SAM5_27-04-2016_11:20:11.md5
-rw-rw-r--   1 ateam    ateam          0 Apr 27 11:21 SAM5_27-04-2016_11:21:20.md5
-rw-rw-r--   1 ateam    ateam         63 Apr 25 10:38 SAM6_25-04-2016_10:38:38.md5
-rw-rw-r--   1 ateam    ateam         63 Apr 27 11:18 SAM6_27-04-2016_11:18:25.md5
```

Can someone explain why the filehandlers are coming up empty? I verified the printing of the files. They all print just fine into the array and the file handlers are opening... What else could be wrong since the files are not empty??? (well all except that one... )

Just for a look into the file... in case that would matter. 
Opening the first file I get:

```
03c0cf2ab0da62832bfc6970d4505746  SAM4_27-04-2016_11:17:22.csv
```

EDIT::: 
I made a slight adjustment to the file:

```
if (($first1 cmp $first2) == 0) {
            if (tell($fh1) == -1){ print "No lines\n";}
            else {my $line1= <$fh1>;  print "$line1\n"; }
            if (eof $fh2){ print "No lines2\n";}
            else { my $line2= <$fh2>; print "$line2\n"; }
            close $fh1;                     close $fh2;
}
```

And got this output instead:

```
2.SAM5_27-04-2016_11:21:20.md5 SAM5_27-04-2016_11:20:11.md5
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at mulftptest line 53.

No lines2
2.SAM6_27-04-2016_11:18:25.md5 SAM6_25-04-2016_10:38:38.md5
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at mulftptest line 53.

No lines2
2.SAM4_27-04-2016_11:19:06.md5 SAM4_27-04-2016_11:17:22.md5
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at mulftptest line 53.

No lines2
```

Essentially, I understand that this is telling me that I'm attempting to use a "empty" variable. However, I do not see why its empty.

Comment: @eballes it defaults to '<', so I don't believe that is the problem. Though for readability/maintainability you should always specify it

Comment: '<:encoding(UTF-8)' This thing?

Comment: I tried it, it didnt help.

Comment: You're sure the files are open? [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) returns 0 if the files are closed.

Comment: `$i + 3` should really be `@md5files - $i - 1`, but that isn't the problem you are trying to solve. Also you should enable `use strict;` and `use warnings;` if you aren't already using them

Comment: Yes they are. I changed this: if   ( eof $fh1 ), to this: if (tell($fh1) == -1)... It went into the else and printed this: "Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at mulftptest line 53"

Comment: Do you run pl script from 'md5sum' dir?

Comment: No, I run it from the directory the script is in.

Comment: Note that they're file *handles* file handlers are something completely different

Comment: Which is line 53 of your program? It's suspicious that you have shown only thirty or so lines, so there is a lot more to your real code. Would you post all of it, please?

Comment: @Borodin the rest is not shown because it is commented out. Also, what do you mean abut your first comment specifically? Line 53 would be line 24 here.

Comment: I just mean that you are using the wrong term. *filehandlers* is wrong, and you mean *file handles*

Comment: Do you realise that you have a rogue file `SAM4_27-04 2016_11:19:06.md5` that has a space between the month and the year instead of an underscore?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: That's wrong. The OP means to pair up files according to their first four characters. The values returned by `readdir` are probably delivered in lexical order of their names, so they should be accessed as `$md5files[$i]` and `$md5files[$i+1]` while the loop increments `$i` by two. Your suggestion expects the second file of each pair to be ordered backwards, like `SAM4_1`, `SAM5_1`, `SAM6_1`, `SAM6_2`, `SAM5_2`, `SAM4_2`; while the OP's code works for `SAM4_1`, `SAM5_1`, `SAM6_1`, `SAM4_2`, `SAM5_2`, `SAM6_2`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Neither assumption is proper, and the names should be accumulated into a hash of prefixes before being processed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that `readdir` returns only the file names, without any path information

That means you are opening `SAM5_27-04-2016_11:21:20.md5` in the current working directory, and not in the `md5sum` directory. Ordinarily your open calls would have failed, but it seems that you have spurious empty files with the same names in your script directory

If you write your open calls like this instead then it should work for you

```
open my $fh1, '<', "$md5dir/$file1" or die "Fail to open file $file1: $!";
```

And don't use `tell` for this purpose. It will return zero at the start whether the file is empty or not. You really want `-s $fh1` which returns the size of the file in bytes, and can be used on the file name or the open file handle

Comment: Would tell return 0 at the start only in this case? I thought tell was useful for this sort of purpose.

Comment: Something is telling me that this is right.. Let me verify it in this morning and then I will bring this answer into acceptance. Thanks.

Comment: @noc_coder: `tell` returns the number of bytes read so far from the file. Immediately after you open the file you have read zero bytes, so `tell` will return zero whether or not there is anything more to read

Comment: This was it! Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you need something like this. I'm pretty sure you have a directory of files that contain MD5 checksums and want to compare them

I've made this more straightforward in these ways

- I have [`use autodie`](https://metacpan.org/pod/autodie) at the top of the program. That is a pragma that checks most Perl IO operations, and saves you verifying whether every `open` call succeeded. It was introduced into core perl for v5.10.1 and is reliable
- I've added a `use constant` for the path to the directory of MD5 files
- I use `glob` instead of `opendir` / `readdir` to find all files in the `md5sum` directory that end with `.md5`. `glob` will never return the pseudo-directories `.` and `..`, but there is always a chance that `xx.md5` may be a directory if someone has been weird. You might want to add a check

There's a loop to build a hash that relates every "prefix" (a prefix being all characters in the filename before the first underscore) to every file with that prefix

That hash is checked to make sure that there are exactly to files in the directory for every prefix. That seemed to be in keeping with the original checks

Now that there is a hash that relates every prefix to two files, the problem seems to be solved. My code displays every prefix together with the names of its two files and the MD5 string that they contain

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

use constant MD5_DIR => '...plib/test/md5sum';    #IN YOUR PROG, IS THE FULL PATH
chdir MD5_DIR;

my %files;

# Build a hash of files collected by prefix
#
for my $file ( glob '*.md5' ) {
    next unless my ($prefix) = $file =~ / ^ ( [^_]+ ) /x;
    push @{ $files{$prefix} }, $file;
}


# Check that there are exactly two files with each prefix
#
{
    my $errors;

    while ( my ($prefix, $files) = each %files ) {

        my $n = @$files;

        if ( @$files != 2 ) {
            warn qq{$n files fouhd for prefix "${prefix}_"\n};
            ++$errors;
        }
    }

    die "Dying because errors found in source directory" if $errors;
}

# Display every pair of files by prefix
#
while ( my ($prefix, $files) = each %files ) {

    my ($file1, $file2) = sort @$files;

    print "Prefix: $prefix\n";

    for my $file ( sort @$files ) {
        open my $fh, '<', $file;
        my $md5 = <$fh>;
        $md5 =~ s/\s+\z//;
        print "    File: $file\n";
        print "        MD5: $md5\n";
    }
}
```